# What's the best way to create an image of an old Mac floppy disk with an eye to further analysis?

Tags: mac, disk-image, floppy

I have an old Mac formatted 1.44 MB floppy disk that I want to read in Ubuntu 18.04. When I tried to read it under Windows with the MacDisk app it says that the Mac volume header can't be found. I'm assuming the disk is just old and corrupt.

I was thinking it would make sense to use [dd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dd.1.html) to get an image of the disk that I could then try to analyze somehow. Is dd the best way to do this or is there some other method that will make for a more easily analyzed image?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to image the disk in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I also have no idea why the site prefaced the question with "MacOS X". I didn't add that and this has nothing to do with OS X.